# Manual function call in Scheme

Tags: scheme

```
(define legal?
  (lambda (try legal-pl)
    (letrec
        ((good?
          (lambda (new-pl up down)
            (cond
              ((null? new-pl) #t)
              (else 
                (let ((next-pos (car new-pl)))
                  (and
                    (not (= next-pos try))
                    (not (= next-pos up))
                    (not (= next-pos down))
                    (good? (cdr new-pl)
                           (add1 up)
                           (sub1 down)))))))))
      (good? legal-pl (add1 try) (sub1 try)))))
```

I am trying to walk through the function above. Here's a manual call I did. Please, see if that's in/correct:

```
(legal?  3 '(1 4 8))
(good? '(1 4 8) 4 2)
(good? '(4 8) 5 1)
(good? '(8) 6 0)
(good? '() 7  -1)
#t
```

If not correct, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This program works fine in DrRacket's stepper. Start DrRacket, set the language level to "Intermediate with Lambda", put your program (and the call to `legal?`) in the buffer, and click the "step" button.  This should show you the steps of the program, one at a time. (There are quite a lot more than 4 steps.)

Let me know if you have any trouble with this.

Comment: @ John, thanks for answering. I did as you said, but got "All of the definitions have been successfully evaluated". No steps shown.

Comment: @user134627 did you "place the call `(legal?  3 '(1 4 8))` as the last line in your buffer, and click the 'step' button"?

Comment: @ Will Ness, I forgot to do just that. Thank you very much! Also, I am super happy @John suggested DrRacket. Very handy and awesome.

Comment: @user134627 notifications don't work with that space after `@`. there mustn't be any space there. cheers. :) and you're welcome.